# Position relative and background-color: can't cover the page

Tags: php, html, css

I can't get why a position relative div at the bottom of my page leaves, if it goes over the height of the screen, white space underneath. I have a background-color gradient as bg so i guess i can't replace it with an image. I can't know the height of the div because i have some php printing inside of it and I can't know how height it will be.

```
<html style="min-height:100%;">
   <head></head>
   <body style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6699ff -13%, #00ffff 133%) repeat-x;">
      <?php
         print("<br><div></div><div style=\"position:relative;max-width:50%;height:inherit;margin:20px auto;\"><div style=\"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;\" class=\"usage\">Istruzioni:<br>");
         Some php printing inside the div
         print("</div><div style=\"position:absolute;top:0;right:0;\" class=\"usage\">Stringa in ingresso: <br> More printing
         </div></div>");
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any tip?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? As in what is the visual effect you are trying to achieve? That might help us help you.

Comment: and min-height:100vh to body

Comment: This might be totally unrealted, but I suggest using resetcss just to give it a try cuz sometimes the page itself adds some unnecessary padding.

Comment: @GSquadron it's not a padding problem, i got a padding:0 on html (this is a small portion of my code but the problem is with the div)

Comment: @Craig I want my background-color: gradient [...] to cover the whole page even if a relative positioned div is at the bottom. Now it is overflowing from the height of my page and it is showing some white space underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a fixed gradient background:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
html { min-height: 100%; }

body {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #6699ff 0%, #00ffff 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #6699ff 0%, #00ffff 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, #6699ff 0%, #00ffff 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #6699ff 0%, #00ffff 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.main-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.usage {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main-container">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="usage">
    <p>Istruzioni:<br>
      Some php printing inside the div</p>
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;" class="usage">
    <p>Stringa in ingresso: <br>
      More printing </p>
    <p>More printing </p>
    <p>More printing</p>
    <p> More printing</p>
    <p>More printing </p>
    <p>More printing</p>
    <p>More printing</p>
    <p>More printing</p>
    <p>More printing</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why ? this will help him yo cover the screen ? i don't think so

Comment: I'll give it a try asap

Comment: Excuse me, now that i solved this problem there is another one: the relative positioned div has the height of zero and there is literally no margin at the bottom of the page. Adding a margin in the html or in the body does not work for me. Also the mozilla browser element's inspector shows that my body and my html "box model(?)" end at the end of the height of my screen. Is that something normal or did i just do something wrong?

Comment: Of course its height is 0px because it contains absolute elements. Same thing apply to body. i added a solution to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried playing with your code.

I think your problem is mainly because of the **"height: inherit"** that you added to the relatively positioned div.

**Try removing that and see if it works.**

**CodePen:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpaXoP

```
<html style="min-height:100%;">

<head></head>

<body style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6699ff -13%, #00ffff 133%) repeat-x;">
    <br>
    <div></div>
    <div style="position:relative;max-width:50%;margin:20px auto;">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" class="usage">Istruzioni:
            <br> Some php printing inside the div
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;" class="usage">Stringa in ingresso:
            <br> More printing
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually it was a try i forgot about and i didn&#39;t remove it in the code I pasted. That&#39;s not the problem probably but i&#39;ll try later.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problems recently.
I used in a css file

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

For me it worked